# MATE - change menu appearance

Tags: customization, ubuntu-mate

Hey guys would you help me change the looks of menu from [image: old menu] to [image: new menu]

Also any cinnamon look like theme?

Comment: That is called the `MATE Menu`  and you can add it to the panel when you right click it and choose `Add To Panel`.  However, you will have to remove all the stuff on the left side of the panel so that you can move the `MATE Menu` all the way to the left.  I can write an answer later, I am just not in a good position to do screen captures on this system.

Comment: @Terrance thnx that really helped , I hope to you add answer soon , but it already solved my problem

Comment: You're very welcome!  OK, I answered quickly.  I did some quick from a VM I had here.   =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add the `MATE Menu` you will remove the other stuff that is up on the bar.

1. Right-click anywhere on the panel in a blank spot and choose `Add to Panel`.

[image]

2. Choose MATE Menu from the list, then click Add.

[image]

3. Remove the existing menu from the panel by right-clicking it and choosing `Remove from panel`.

[image]

4. Right-click on the newly added menu and choose `Move`

[image]

5. Drag it to the left and left-click when in the place you want it.  Then right-click and choose `Lock to panel`.

[image]

6. Enjoy your new menu.

[image]

Hope this helps!